# How to remove items from 2 lists based on duplicate items in one of the lists while maintaining order?

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists:

```
list_1 = [[1,1], [1,3], [1,1], [1,4]]
list_2 = ["string_1", "string_2", "string_3", "string_4"]
```

My goal is to remove the duplicate sublists from `list_1` and also the strings in `list_2` that have the same index as the sublists removed, while maintaining the order of the sublists.

I found that I can remove duplicate sublists while maintaining the order of the sublists in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936362/maintaining-the-order-of-the-elements-in-a-frozen-set) using:

```
from itertools import * 
def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element

list(unique_everseen(list_1, key=frozenset))
```

But it's not clear how to match the removed sublists indices on `list_2`

Optimal output:

```
new_list_1 = [[1,1], [1,3], [1,4]]
new_list_2 = ["string_1", "string_2", "string_4"]
```

Comment: Why not zip the lists together, do the removals, then unzip the lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```py
list_1 = [[1,1], [1,3], [1,1], [1,4]]
list_2 = ["string_1", "string_2", "string_3", "string_4"]

output_1, output_2 = [], []

seen = set()

for sublst, s in zip(list_1, list_2):
    if (tup := tuple(sublst)) in seen:
        continue

    seen.add(tup)

    output_1.append(sublst)
    output_2.append(s)

print(output_1) # [[1, 1], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
print(output_2) # ['string_1', 'string_2', 'string_4']
```

Note that you need to store `tuple(sublst)` (not `sublst` itself) in the set `seen`, since a `sublst` like `[1,1]` is not hashable.

Answer (score 0):

```
res1 = []
res2 = []

for i in range(len(list_1)):
    if list_1[i] not in list_1[:i]:
        res1.append(list_1[i])
        res2.append(list_2[i])
```

or

```
res1, res2 = map(list, zip(*[(list_1[i], list_2[i]) for i in range(len(list_1)) if list_1[i] not in list_1[:i]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep an additional list to keep track of duplicates in list_1 and then use the lists of comprehension to shorten the resulting lists.

```
list_1 = [[1,1], [1,3], [1,1], [1,4]]
list_2 = ["string_1", "string_2", "string_3", "string_4"]

selector = [True] * len(list_1)
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    for j in range(i):
        if list_1[j] == list_1[i]:
            selector[i] = False
            break

new_list_1 = [element for i, element in enumerate(list_1) if selector[i]]
new_list_2 = [element for i, element in enumerate(list_2) if selector[i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `set()` and `zip`

```
def deduplicate(items):
     seen = set()
     for a, b in items:
         a = tuple(a)
         if not a in seen:
             seen.add(a)
             yield list(a), b

list_1 = [[1,1], [1,3], [1,1], [1,4]]
list_2 = ["string_1", "string_2", "string_3", "string_4"]        
tmp = list(deduplicate(zip(list_1, list_2)))
print([x[0] for x in tmp])
print([x[1] for x in tmp])


# [[1, 1], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
# ['string_1', 'string_2', 'string_4']
```

Comment: Assigning the tuple to another variable to not create a new list object should would be a bit more efficient - while it could be wanted that we clone the object. Less error prone later.

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation based on your code, simply modifying your function to return the indexes of unique elements instead of the elements themselves:

```
from itertools import *

list_1 = [[1,1], [1,3], [1,1], [1,4]]
list_2 = ["string_1", "string_2", "string_3", "string_4"]
 
def unique_everseen(iterable):
#   Lists indexes of unique elements in iterable, preserving order.
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    for element in iterable:
        k = frozenset(element)
        if k not in seen:
            seen_add(k)
            yield iterable.index(element)

unique_indexes = [i for i in unique_everseen(list_1)]
print(unique_indexes)
filtered_list_1 = [list_1[i] for i in unique_indexes]
filtered_list_2 = [list_2[i] for i in unique_indexes]
print(filtered_list_1)
print(filtered_list_2)
```